# Weird "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im running into the following error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes:
```

I know this is a generally asked question, but none of the answers provided seem to work for me. The thing is, i already have this 2 lines in my "parent" model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

AND

```
attr_accessible  :childmodel_attributes
```

I had run into this error in the past, and those 2 lines succefully solved the issue.. But they dont now. BTW, the "protected attributes" are ALL the fields in my "child" model, not just certain ones.

Hope someone can help me, im stuck and dont know what else to do.

This is the full error line:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: linea, origen_comp, conector, char_ini, char_fin, modopremio_id, codigo_opc, ochar_ini, ochar_fin
```

This is what the "child_model" has

```
:consorcio_id, :productosacierto_id, :clave, :linea, :origen_comp, :conector, :char_inic, :char_fin, :modopremio_id, codigo_opc, :ochar_ini, :onchar_fin
```

(Sidenote, the "parent/child model" names are just for reference, they are not their true names (productosacierto AND productosregla) would be it.

**Parent Model (Productosacierto)**

```
has_many :productosregla
accepts_nested_attributes_for :productosregla, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
attr_accessible  :productosregla_attributes, :producto_id, :consorcio_id, :clave, :descripcion, :una_condicion
default_scope order: 'id'
self.table_name = "hproductos_aciertos"
```

**Child Model (Productosregla)**

```
self.table_name = "hproductos_reglas"  
belongs_to :productosacierto
attr_accessible :consorcio_id, :productosacierto_id, :clave, :linea, :origen_comp, :conector, :char_inic, :char_fin, :modopremio_id, codigo_opc, :ochar_ini, :ochar_fin 
default_scope order: 'id'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full error? what attribute is it saying it can't mass-assign

Comment: @Sam D Its not rails 4, rails 3.2. TopGunCoder, i edited my answer.

Comment: Oscar, can you show us the contents of your model file?

Comment: Sure Danny Van Hoof, i will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an exact copy of your child model, then I guess the comma at the end of the attr_accessible line is the problem!

Comment: Sorry, i left out a field, i will edit to fix it. This is not the issue as it would've thrown a "sintax error" if that was the case. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of embarrassed right now. There were several sintax errors on my model and thats what was causing this issue. I took it for granted that rails would throw a sintax error if there were some, specially when it's so delicate when it comes to writting code in the model...

This is what i had:

```
attr_accessible :consorcio_id, :productosacierto_id, :clave, :linea, :origen_comp, :conector, :char_inic, :char_fin, :modopremio_id, codigo_opc, :ochar_ini, :ochar_fin
```

This is what it was supposed to be:

```
attr_accessible :consorcio_id, :productosacierto_id, :clave, :linea, :origen_comp, :conector, :char_ini, :char_fin, :modopremio_id, :codigo_opc, :ochar_ini, :ochar_fin
```

As you can see, there was a ":" missing before the codigo_opc param, and also the char_ini param had an extra "c" that didnt belong. Thanks everyone who helped, this taught me to make sure never to assume anything.